# (7, 23) CS1001 Identifier Expected for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am new to coding in c# and was trying to make the ball appear and launch towards you but it has CS1001 and I am really confused, I would appreciate it if someone could help.

```
 public GameObject("ball");

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float y = 50;
    float dX = y * 0.8f;
    // y = (vNotY ^ 2) / 2g
    float vNotY = y * 2 * Physics.gravity.y;
    vNotY = Mathf.Sqrt(vNotY);
    // t = 2 * v0y / g
    float time = 2 * vNotY / Physics.gravity.y;
    // v = d / t
    float vX = dX / time;
    Vector3 force = new Vector3(vX, vNotY, 0);
    ball.rigidbody.AddForce(force);
}
```

}

Comment: What is `public GameObject("ball");` supposed to be? That is not valid C#

Answer (score 1):

```
public GameObject("ball");
```

change to

```
public GameObject ball;
```

variable declaration

accessibility class variablename ;